# Javascript REGEX - Tricky Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been banging my head all day trying to figure out how to formulate what seems to be a tricky regex expression. Here we go:

```
NAME=JOHN,SMITH
```

I want to  select "JOHN" and "SMITH" (not the comma nor the equals sign)

In other words, I want an expression to select LETTERS after an equals sign (while not including the equals sign itself) regardless of whether or not the letters/words are separated by a comma. I'm afraid I can't change the formatting.

Thanks. I'm using JavaScript btw.

---

EDIT: Here is what I managed to put together so far. `/=(\D[^=\n,]+)/g` However, this still selects the equals sign and doesn't add any other words that may come after a comma.

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: regardless of whether or not the letters/words are separated by a comma.  This means this example you would want the result be 'JOHN,SMITH' ?

Comment: @fuyushimoya no the name could be just "JANE" or 'JOHN" and "SMITH" (either just a first name or a first and last name seperated by just a comma)

Comment: don't overthink it: `/NAME=(\w+),?(\w+)?/`

Comment: If you don't specifically need a regex, you can simply extract everything that comes after "=" and use a simple split function with "," as a separator.

Comment: seems like it is simple.... match equal, match anything but comma, match the rest....

Comment: @desbo I just ran your expression through regex101.com it seems that it selects NAME= and the commas as well, which is not what I want.

Comment: Is the desired result `JOHNSMITH` or `JOHN` and `SMITH`?  If there's no comma separator, then what separator is used? Space?

Comment: sigh.. please post actual "before" and "after" examples for what you actually want.  e.g. what do you want a result variable to actually contain. show an actual example or two

Comment: @PM77-1 JOHN and SMITH

Comment: @Walendas read up on capturing groups in regular expressions. you've failed to do some really basic research here.

Comment: How do you separate `JOHN` from `SMITH` when the comma is missing?

Comment: You have comments all over the place changing the requirements and context.  Please update your question to show full requirements, what this is for, etc..at face value, this regex is not "tricky" at all. What's "tricky" is making it work within the context of some other thing that you aren't being clear about

Comment: @CrayonViolent Sorry for the confusion. Will take another crack at it myself and we'll see from there.

Comment: `However, this still selects the equals sign` Well, JavaScript can't do lookbehind assertions, so `(?<==)` is out of the question. `I want to select "JOHN" and "SMITH" (not the comma nor the equals sign)` Ok, for that you need capture groups around the names `(JOHN),(SMITH)`. `I'm afraid I can't change the formatting.` Then you are out of luck, because that's what regex does, they get _continuous_ characters. That's the premise.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to select "JOHN" and "SMITH"

Use this :

```
'NAME=JOHN,SMITH'.match(/\=(\w+),?(\w+)/)
```

the result will be on the *second* and *third* index of the array :

`["=JOHN,SMITH", "JOHN", "SMITH"]`

Comment: I absolutely agree with you except that I am also using a plugin (probably should have mentioned that above) that accepts nothing but a regex expression. (I couldn't use .match() ) if I wanted to. So frustrating!

Comment: The regex is nothing but `\=(\w+),?(\w+)`

Comment: @Walendas - Then please post your **real** requirements.

Comment: @Walendas What does your plugin except as a parameter ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir nothing but a regex expression

Comment: @Walendas and what does it do ? maybe he is doing a match behind the scenes ? what's the name of the plugin

Comment: @RoyiNamir it's [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html) - the simple mode definition. I'm doing code highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
/\w+(?!.*=)/g
```

That will do a negative lookahead meaning you want a word: \w+  that is NOT before any number of characters plus an = sign.

Then the global will give you multiple matches excluding a comma. I believe this is what you're looking for?  You won't have any match groups, but I don't believe you need any from what you've said so far.

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/mT9gL3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
var str = 'NAME=JOHN,SMITH';
str = str.replace(/NAME\=([A-Z]+?)\,([A-Z]+?)/g,'$1 $2');
alert(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5ed7gcr/1/

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do it for you

`/(.+?(?==))|([^,?=?]+)/g`

The first part, `(.+?(?==))`, uses a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to search for the `=` character. It basically groups anything before the `=` character

The second part, `([^,?=?]+)` groups everything that isn't a `,` or a `=`, so it groups the other two components of your search string. Tell me if this works for you :)

If you do not want the `NAME` part, you can use simply `/(\w+(?!.*=))/g`.

If you do not want it to be grouped, you can remove the parentheses which gives you `/.+?(?==)|[^,?=?]+/g` and `/\w+(?!.*=)/g`.

You can test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/#javascript)